# How to get rid of ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, jupyter, training-data

I am running the following code

```
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df[['year']], df.income)
```

and after doing that I am getting the following error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '19,703,399.30'
```

year value is like 1960-2016
income looks like 19,703,399.30

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do some preprocessing to get rid of the commas?

Comment: the error suggests you are having string in 'year' column. just do conversion df['year'].astype(float)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
df['income'] = df['income'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)
df['year'] = df['year'].astype(float)
reg.fit(df[['year']], df.income)
```